# Gradually slow read in Netezza from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, netezza

I'm doing fetch from one table from Netezza, by java code with 4 threads( runs overnight).
At start it takes approximately 7seconds, but gradually this average time increases 200 seconds over 24 hours.
I've double checked if it is network issue or someone else's query causing slow down. So its only my program working on this database. 
Any idea why?

Query is select statement:
`select col1,col2 from tab where id >? and id< ?`
Everytime this same query runs with different inputs provided from java code.
Table contains around 150,000,000 records.
Though input changes result are fetched in same batchsize.

For example,
if first query is `select col1,col2 from tab where id >1 and id< 100`

next will be `select col1,col2 from tab where id >201 and id< 300`

keeping records fetch of 100(in this example).

I use Jdbctemplete to execute these queries, which use connections from Pool I believe.

Comment: its Not quite clear to me based on your description: 1) is it the same exact query you issue every time? 2) Does the query return the same exact result every time (number of rows/columns) 3) have you looked at the access plans? 4) Do you re-connect for each query? 5) do you commit for each query?

Comment: Quite a wild guess, but maybe something like String += being done. (No offense intended)

Comment: @LarsGOlsen added information you asked for,
though I haven't checked access plans, will do that.